# In Ubuntu, Should I update the Chrome Browser through the browser or the system's package manager?

Tags: google-chrome

Under Ubuntu, Should I use the green arrow that shows up at the top right corner of the browser to update the browser or should I use the system's package manager to update Chrome(apt) ?

If I use the green arrow to update, when trying to uninstall Chrome(sudo apt purge chrome), will all the files associated with the Chrome Browser  be deleted just like how they would be deleted if you used the package manager to update ch

Comment: When you installed chrome should have been a dialog asking if you wanted it updated with the system.  If you click yes, then let ubuntu do the updating.

Comment: i don't remember...is there a way to bring the dialog back again ?

Comment: Chrome version should be 84.0.4147.105 if Ubuntu is updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"purge" will remove everything including settings.

> just like how they would be deleted if you used the package manager to update chrome

No, apt never uses purge automatically. It uses "apt remove".

Chrome is not part of a default install and if it is in the apt repository then you are using a 3rd party repository. So... either method will use the same method to update: either from an update through that repository or by adding a new repository where it disables the old one.